# There is a problem when i run this program is not show in a ouput driver is insured

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
void main()
{
int age;
char ms,sex;
clrscr();
printf("Enter martial status,sex and age:");
scanf("%c%c%d",&ms,&sex,&age);
if(ms=='m')  //ms=martial status and m is married
{
printf("Driver is insured");
}
else
{
   if(ms=='u')    //u is unmarried
   {
     if(sex=='m' && age>30)
     {
     printf("Driver is insured");
     }
     else
     printf("Driver is not insured");
   }
   else
   {
     if(sex=='f' && age>25)
     printf("Driver is insured");
     else
     printf("Driver is not insured");
   }
}
getch();
}
```

1. when I run this program the output is not correct that I need?
2. when I run this program and input u f 34 then it shows Driver is not insured why?
3. please tell me where I go wrong.

Comment: oh that my mistake

Comment: but there is also problem that I mention on above

Comment: Try `scanf(" %c %c%d",&ms,&sex,&age);` or `scanf(" %c %c %d",&ms,&sex,&age);`.